# How can I dump my SQL Server Database Schema to a human readable & printable format?

Tags: sql-server

I want to generate something like the following:

### LineItems

- Id
- ItemId
- OrderId
- Price

### Orders

- Id
- CustomerId
- DateCreated

### Customers

- Id
- FirstName
- LastName
- Email

I don't need all the relationships, the diagram that will never print correctly, the metadata, anything. Just a list of the tables and their columns in a simple text format.

Has anyone done this before? Is there a simple solution?

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: This seems more appropriate for ServerFault. I have voted to migrate it there.

Comment: developers don't need to see their database schema? that's reserved for sysadmins?

Comment: {x group} don't need to see there {y stuff}? that's reserved for {z group}?. Just because they need to, doesn't mean the question isn't more appropriate for a different place. Developers need to eat as well, but you don't see them posting how to cook a roast here...

Comment: This isn't a serverfault question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of good tools out there to do this for you, but for something quick and dirty you can try something like this:

```
SELECT t.name, c.name
FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this, then pasted into excel, created a pivot table and ended up with EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing some code for that, you could consider the SqlConnection.GetSchema() method(s). You can find more information on obtaining the database schema [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx).

You would need to access the 'Tables' and 'Columns' schema collections to get the information you require. You can pick up only the very basic information like the table and column names, although you have access to a lot more details